# Proximity search in a set of case results

Tags: civicase, advanced-search

When I used the advanced search screen, **displaying results as contacts** I can get proximity and case criteria to work together (for instance anyone 50 miles from zip code 12345 with an ongoing facility support case).

But when I change the results to **show the results as cases** it tells me there are no matches found. (Same exact criteria, I just want to see a list of facility support cases in the area).

I can combine other criteria in the address section, just not the "Find contacts within" field. Is this a bug? Is anyone else able to get this to work?

I'm using Civi 5.39.4 and Drupal 7

Comment: Not sure if this is coincidental but this just happened: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3163

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep an eye on that issue to see if it's related/clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

This should be available in 5.51 with this PR by @coleman: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23597. It works for me for the above criteria.

[image]